# How to use sed or any other command to remove all the lines between stream

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a pdf file, and I want to remove all the lines in between Rstream and efd stream. Here is how the document looks like

```
PDFNUM NUM obj/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width NUM/Height NUM/BitsPerCompofeft NUM/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Filter[/DCTDecode]/DecodeParms[]/Lefgth NUM NUM RstreamJFIFddC
(NUMAQaqNUMBRNUMbr()NUMCDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzNUMAQaqNUMBRNUMbr()NUMCDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefgh
.....
.....
((((((((((((((QEQEQEQEQEW((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((efdstreamefdobjNUM NUM objNUMefdobjNUM NUM obj/Lefgth NUM NUM RstreamqNUM NUM NUM NUM NUM NUM cm/INUM DoQefdstreamefdobjNUM NUM objNUMefdobjNUM NUM obj/Type/Page/Pareft NUM NUM R/Resources NUM NUM R/Rotate NUM/MediaBox[NUM NUM NUM NUM]/Coftefts[NUM NUM R]efdobjNUM NUM obj/ProcSet[/PDF/ImageB/Text]/XObject/INUM NUM NUM RefdobjNUM NUM obj/CreatiofDate (DNUM)/Producer (SamsufgMNUMLX)/Creator (ScafPDFMaker NUM)efdobjNUM NUM obj/Type/Pages/Couft NUM/Kids[NUM NUM R ]efdobjNUM NUM obj/Type/Catalog/Pages NUM NUM RefdobjxrefNUM NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f trailer/Size NUM/Iffo NUM NUM R/Root NUM NUM RstartxrefNUMEOF
```

How can I use sed to remove everything between Rstream at the top (beginning of my document) and efdstream at almost the bottom to only stay with the document specifications like the producer, creator, etc

I found patterns and reduced the original document. I renamed all the patterns with one word NUM by using sed command so that it can be easy for me to see what to remove. Here it is

```
-$ cat path | tr \n \f | tr -cd "[A-Za-z0-9 ()/\f]" | sed s/stream.*endstream/STREAM/| sed s/[0-9][0-9]*/NUM/g | sed "s/NUM NUM n/PTR/g".
```

This only makes a replacement with the word NUM. The result should only keep the bottom of the file

```
objNUMefdobjNUM NUM obj/Lefgth NUM NUM RstreamqNUM NUM NUM NUM NUM NUM cm/INUM DoQefdstreamefdobjNUM NUM objNUMefdobjNUM NUM obj/Type/Page/Pareft NUM NUM R/Resources NUM NUM R/Rotate NUM/MediaBox[NUM NUM NUM NUM]/Coftefts[NUM NUM R]efdobjNUM NUM obj/ProcSet[/PDF/ImageB/Text]/XObject/INUM NUM NUM RefdobjNUM NUM obj/CreatiofDate (DNUM)/Producer (SamsufgMNUMLX)/Creator (ScafPDFMaker NUM)efdobjNUM NUM obj/Type/Pages/Couft NUM/Kids[NUM NUM R ]efdobjNUM NUM obj/Type/Catalog/Pages NUM NUM RefdobjxrefNUM NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f NUM NUM f trailer/Size NUM/Iffo NUM NUM R/Root NUM NUM RstartxrefNUMEOF
```

Comment: Something like `/Rstream/,/efdstream/{//!d;s/.*DoQefdstreamefdobjNUM NUM /&\n/;D}` might work. Using `//!` to process the starting and ending lines differently, then inserting a line break where you want to break, then using `D` to delete up to that line break.   But I'm not totally clear on how to break where you want in that final line, so this is just a suggestion.  HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sed here but Perl has more powerful regular expressions and is a drop in replacement for most sed regex.

To remove all data from the first occurrence of Rstream to the last occurrence of efdstream:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/Rstream.*efdstream//s' <filename.pdf >new.pdf
```

To remove all data between each of the occurrences of Rstream and efdstream:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/Rstream.*?efdstream//sg' <filename.pdf >new.pdf
```

The -0777 means read in and operate on the entire file at once rather than line by line.  This is necessary for the multiline substitution.  The -pe means this is a streaming one liner.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

Also read these regex references:

1. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html
2. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html
3. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html

Perl has the most powerful regular expressions of any language.  You could write a full parser for your task if need be.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here is 3 lines `awk` (standard Linux gawk) script

`script.awk`

```
split($0,arr,"efdstream") > 1{print arr[1]; next;}  # read and print the head of efdstream line
split($0,arr,"Rstream") > 1 {print arr[2]; next;}   # read and print the tail of Rstream line
1  # print any other lines
```

running:

```
awk -f scirpt.awk input.pdf
```

or one liner:

```
awk '{split($0,arr,"efdstream") > 1{print arr[1]; next;}split($0,arr,"Rstream") > 1 print arr[2]; next;} 1}' input.pdf
```

output of provided pdf file in question.

```
JFIFddC
(NUMAQaqNUMBRNUMbr()NUMCDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzNUMAQaqNUMBRNUMbr()NUMCDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefgh
.....
.....
((((((((((((((QEQEQEQEQEW((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed '/Rstream/,/efdstream/{s/.*DoQefdstreamefdobjNUM NUM /&\n/;D}' pdf-file`

In the range from the Rstream line to the efdstream line:

- `s/.*DoQefdstreamefdobjNUM NUM /&\n/` - add a line break where the OP wants to begin retaining data on the final line. `&` is everything that matched.
- `D` - delete everything up to the first line break, for every line in the range.  This deletes the entirety of every line except the last, where it deletes up to the inserted line break

Given the input, that produces the expected output... the last line, truncated after efdstream and the two associated NUMs.

If `NUM` is your shorthand for `[0-9]+`, then you can make it:

`sed -E '/Rstream/,/efdstream/{s/.*DoQefdstreamefdobj[0-9]+ [0-9]+ /&\n/;D}' pdf-file`

This adds the `-E` flag for extended regex to enable the `+`.

If there is an uncertain number of NUMs, you could use this:

`sed -E '/Rstream/,/efdstream/{s/.*DoQefdstreamefdobj([0-9]+ )+/&\n/;D}' pdf-file`